# Динамическое создание комнат для группы участников в socket.io одним из участников

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Доброе время суток. Подскажите ребята как можно одному участнику чата добавить в комнату несколько других при помощи `socket.io` В голову приходит мысль о `socket.to(idSocket).join(myRoom);` но увы такой реализации в документации не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант хранить все текущие подключения в кеш объекте, по уникальному идентификатору можете достать нужный вам сокет и присоединить его к комнате.

```
const sockets = {}

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
   socket.on('save', (name)=>{  // эмитится с клиента, для сохранения
       sockets[name] = socket;
   }) 
   socket.on('addToRoom', (name)=>{
       sockets[name].join(myRoom)
   })
   socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
       for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sockets)){
           if (value.id !== socket.id) continue;
           delete sockets[key]
       }        
   })
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, пусть не идеальный но вариант :)